# Protractor need to break from For LOOP when if is executed

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

Can anyone Please Help me in this in the below code, my requirement is once If is true, I should come out from For loop

===================================================

```
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      
        element(By.xpath("//*[text() = '" + InvoiceREFnumberCompany + "']")).isPresent().then(function(result) {
                if (result )  
                  {
                    element(By.xpath("//*[text() = '" + InvoiceREFnumberCompany + "']")).click();
                 
                   break;
                  }
                
                else
                   {
                     
                            
                     obj1.ClickOnRefreshButton.click();
                        
                      
                }
            });
 }
```

Output
Failures:

1. NPOInvoice-Fire --  NPO Fire Collabrate with  PTC user
   Message:
   [31m    Failed: Illegal break statement[0m
   Stack:
   SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Comment: Do you really need to refresh? If you wait long enough will the element just appear? You might not even need the loop if you use `ExpectedCondition.presenceOf()` instead.

Comment: suggestion for future - if you make your code snippet look neat, you'll have higher chances to have your question answered